# Nginx auth_request and auth_basic

Tags: nginx

Im trying to configure nginx to do user authentication before accessing a resource. Currently my configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location = /test {
    satisfy any;
        auth_basic "test";
        auth_basic_user_file "/usr/local/nginx/htpasswd";        
        auth_request /auth;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;

    }
    location = /auth {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.111.101:8080/auth;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
}
```

So what i want to happen is that nginx should ask the user for password using the "auth_basic" procedure. (this will fail, since the user is not in the auth_basic_user_file )

then nginx should try the "auth_request" and also provide the username/password used in the "auth_basic". Same solution as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299623/nginx-authentication-with-auth-request-module however it seem like nginx is somehow preferring the "authrequest" so this is done first, and the "auth_basic" is executed afterwards.

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Your configuration is correct, using "satisfy any" which exactly for this job. here it's the documentation. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#satisfy. you maybe found a bug or somehting? if you find anything let us know.

Comment: Could not make it work, i tested with multiple nginx versions, i just ended up doing a custom implementation inspired by this: http://www.stavros.io/posts/writing-an-nginx-authentication-module-in-lua/

Comment: I had a same problem and I used your code from this post. It turns out that by proxy_pass for auth was only configured for POST and not GET. Once I turned on GET as well everything worked as charm. Stupid thing was not to check that first (i wasted 3 hours on this before check that GET is not covered)

Answer (score 0):

most important for POST file upload is:

```
proxy_pass_request_body off;
 proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
```

if you only GET you don't need above add

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is intrinsically stateless. Basic authentication relies on state retained in the browser being sent back to the server. The server needs to tell the browser this should switched on. With auth_request, there is state but the mechanism is opaque to nginx.

Given that, there is no mechanism within nginx to differentiate between a client who has not yet attemted basic authorization and a client whom has been authenticated via the auth_request mechanism.

If you merely want to provide 2 different logon methods, then you need to implement them both in the auth provider (or multiplex via an auth provider) not in nginx.

However if you *only* want to use the Basic authorization for a non interactive access, then you coul use the presence of the "Authorization" header as a in indicator to nginx.